# How to work with foreign key in django template and forms?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a special form which represent me a list of data, but the problem is that it works very slowly, so is there something like django `autocomplete_fields` for forms?

my form:

```py
class TripSearchForm(forms.Form):
    departure = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Place.objects.places_for_segment())
    destination = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Place.objects.places_for_segment())
```

```py
 def places_for_segment(self):
        return Place.objects.filter(Q(role=Place.CITY) | Q(role=Place.VILLAGE) | Q(role=Place.TOWN))
```

Comment: You should time each section and each function to see where is your bottleneck and they try to optimize it.

Comment: You mean something like https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2 ? But note that this won't fix inefficient queries or the N+1 queries problem (hint: there's quite some literature on making efficient use of the django ORM).

Answer (score 0):

As a first approach, you can try with [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to prefetch the foreign keys

```
def places_for_segment(self):
    return Place.objects.filter(
        Q(role=Place.CITY) \
        | Q(role=Place.VILLAGE) \
        | Q(role=Place.TOWN)
     ).select_related('name_of_the_foreign_key', 'another_foreign_key')
```